# Kotlin ListBuilder (buildList) making unit test fail

Tags: android, kotlin, unit-testing

Im having a strange issue (at least for me) in which my unit tests are failing because of using ListBuilders, in this case `buildList()`, instead of the common `listOf/mutableListOf`.

Take a look to and example of the test Im talking about:

```
@Test
fun `example test`() {
        // Given
        val fakeList1 = listOf<MyModel1>()

        given(useCase1.execute()).willReturn(Observable.just(fakeList1))

        val captor1 = argumentCaptor<List<UIModel1>>()

        // When
        SUT.onViewCreated()

        // Then
        verify(view).test1(captor1.capture())

        // Assert that Argument Captor captured empty lists
        assertEquals(listOf(UIModel1.EmptyView), captor1.firstValue)
}
```

and an example of the function that is being running in the test:

```
 // test passing
 private fun buildUIList(list: List<MyModel1>): List<UIModel1> {
     val finalList = mutableListOf<UIModel1>()
     if (list.isEmpty()) {
        finalList.add(UIModel1.EmptyView)
        return finalList
     } else {
         finalList.addAll(
            blablabla...
         )
         return finalList
     }
}
```

```
// test failing
private fun buildUIList(list: List<MyModel1>): List<UIModel1> {       
   return buildList {
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
             add(UIModel1.EmptyView)
        } else {
             addAll(
                blablabla...
             )
        }
   }
}
```

Of course needless to say that in runtime they behave exactly the same.
I don't mind changing the implementation at all but at this point it is pure curiosity.
It took me about an hour to figure that out

Thank you all!

Comment: Your test code asserts if the list contains only `UIModel1.EmptyView` but your `allegedly failing? test`  code adds only `NearOpportunityUI.EmptyView`.

Comment: @ocos Oh sorry. I made a typo while trying to simplify the code for better understability. Both of them are `UIModel1.EmptyView`; Ive updated the question. The code is just testing that if my use case returns an empty list then the resulting list includes a `UIModel1.EmptyView` model in it.

Comment: You may investigate the issue in your test code espacially in `mockito` part.

Comment: Well, I appreciate your help but that's precisely the problem I'm having. I don't know where else to look. After researching I have come to the conclusion that the same test works with mutableListOf but not with buildList.

Comment: Your tests are failing ... _how_? Like where / what line / what error?

Comment: Share the actual error message.

Comment: Fails in the verify assertion. verify(view).test1(captor1.capture()). Expected a call on view.test1(list) but its never being called.